# How to make pycharm always recognize imports in the same directory?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I have a file a.py in a directory somewhere inside the project, and in the same directory I have b.py. Inside a.py I want to be able to do:

```
import b
```

This works in Python, but Pycharm doesn't recognize it. Is there a way to make Pycharm always recognize import relative to the directory of the importing file?

EDIT: to clarify the issue, I already have sources root defined, and a.py and b.py are not at the top level. Here is a screenshot showing the issue:
[image]

EDIT 2: based on the comments, this question is invalid and I should not be importing code in the way described.

Comment: Can you provide the full directory structure of your project? When a newer user asks about this kind of things is because they are using the imports in the wrong way. Anyway you can always add the directory as a Source root (right click Mark as source root or something like that)

Comment: I updated the question, with an example directory structure that reproduces the issue, such that none of the provided answers so far solve it.

Comment: If you add `subdir2` as Sourcedir PyCharm should recognize it. Note however that, as I feared, you are simply doing things wrong. You should *not* do `import b` in that way. The fact that you say that "in python it works" suggest you are also running python in the wrong way since what you wrote wouldn't work normally. Inside a package if you want a relative import you should use the relative import syntax which in your case would be `from . import b` and you should run `a.py` from outside `subdir2` as `cd subdir; python -m subdir2.a`.

Comment: What you are doing is working in your development environment but it will not work if you try to create a python package to upload to a repository and install it properly.

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoAlzetta! I wasn't aware this doesn't work when creating a proper package. I tested and confirmed this behavior. This makes pycharm's behavior reasonable, and the question invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder that you're working on

Select "Mark directory as" > "Sources Root"

[image]

Comment: I believe if you add an __init__.py file it will mark it as source, also that way you make sure your code works when installed. This is the correct answer though.

Comment: So, I am aware of sources root, and this does not work if a.py and b.py are somewhere deep inside the source tree, and the source tree is above them.

(regardless of the existence of various \_\_init__.py files on way).

Answer (score 0):

Well this a feature with pycharm already, just mark the source root for your project and pycharm will take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can do `import .b`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports